# How to use federated authentication in an MVC app without making it the default authentication type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, wif, federated-identity

I've set up a new MVC app which is configured to use ADFS for federated authentication (as per [this article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/windows-azure/1158/using-adfs-azure-single-signon-aspnet-mvc)).

Everything is working fine, but I want to change the way it works, and I'm not quite sure how.

When I created the project (in VS2015), there's stuff in Starup.Auth.cs which sets things up to use federated auth:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
        new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Wtrealm = realm,
            MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata,
        });
}
```

This makes it so that anything in my MVC app which is tagged with the `[Authorize]` attribute requires the user to be signed in (and so redirects to the ADFS sign in page).

Instead, I want to decide myself when to make this redirect happen.

How can I modify the configuration so that I can trigger the authentication flow manually, rather than having it tied to `[Authorize]`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to make my own authentication middleware, and if it decides that another authentication provider is required, it issues a call to `context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge()` (like in the `ChallengeResult` helper that comes with a default MVC project in VS2015 that uses "Invidiual Authentication".